# monitoring health status in boolean using prometheus

Tags: prometheus

I want to track the operation status in boolean in Prometheus like `Prometheus.NewGaugeVec()`. I couldn't find an example for doing so.

Does there exist any type where I can push boolean status like  `WithLabelValues("name", "label").Set(true/false)`?

Answer (score 0):

Prometheus can handle only numeric values (float64 internally). (see [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/data_model/#samples)). You need to encode the boolean value into 0 and 1.